# How do I rename file in Heroku running on Spring batch?

Tags: spring, heroku, spring-batch

I have a Java codebase which is being executed on a heroku dyno. The command has executed and the log after that confirms the file is changed but actually it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
File file =null;
String fileName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + env.getProperty("filePath");

try
    {
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {

            //Get the file and rename the same.
            file = new File(fileName);
            if (file!=null && file.exists())
            {
                String renameFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/wardIssue_"+ new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss").format(new Date().getTime()).toString() +"_completed";
                logger.info("File being renamed to {}", renameFile);
                file.renameTo(new File(renameFile));

            }
            logger.info("Batch job completed successfully");;
        }   
    }
```

If you see the `logger.info` section actually prints the renamed file but in the server the file name is not changed.

The same code in my local is working fine i.e. file name is changed.

Should I be running the Java command for this spring batch with `sudo`? Are there any other things that might cause this problem?

I am using a `Procfile` with following command:

```
worker: java -Dserver.port=9002 $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/com.cognitive.bbmp.anukula.batch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you make to it will be lost the next time your dyno restarts, which happens frequently ([at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts)).

Furthermore, each dyno has its *own* ephemeral filesytem. Operations you perform on one dyno have no effect on other dynos, so you can't even make temporary filesystem changes with a worker and expect it to affect web (or any other) dynos.

You'll have to approach your problem in a way that doesn't require files to be renamed if you want to run your code on Heroku.

Comment: Tahnks Chris, this is useful. I am new to this. So, I have to delete then. So, no option fo s3 or ESB like in aws?  One more question then - i tried to do a lot of digging R&D etc. I am not able to autostart or run Spring Batch on one Dyno free instance that is provided. I even added the Procfile with worker: java  -jar target/batch_order_process_0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar etc. None fo this works. However, when i go to console and run it works but it doesnt autorun on build. I am now thinking of just remivign procfile...

Comment: There's no "host my filesystem on ESB" toggle, but you _can_ store objects outside of Heroku's own filesytem. This is [exactly what Heroku recommends for things like user uploads](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3). I'm not familiar enough with Spring to comment on the last part.